# Eror "price must be consistent across all products" etsy

Tags: php, rest, api, etsy

I send "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/listing_id/inventory" but i received error  "price must be consistent across all products"

that's what i give in offerings:

```
[offerings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 14500
                                    [divisor] => 100
                                    [currency_code] => USD
                                    [currency_formatted_short] => $145.00
                                    [currency_formatted_long] => $145.00 USD
                                    [currency_formatted_raw] => 145.00
                                )

                            [quantity] => 7
                            [is_enabled] => 1
                            [is_deleted] => 0
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and you also have to add the parameter [price_on_property], even if Etsy Api say it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to update inventory, you don't include the entire Money object as json.  The price is supplied as a double value only. (ex. "price=29.99")

It would look more like this

```
[offerings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [price] => 145.00
                            [quantity] => 7
                            [is_enabled] => 1
                            [is_deleted] => 0
                        )

                )
```